# Gazebo ignition spawn_entity equivalent

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-ignition, spawn-model, ros2-launch

When designing simulations in Gazebo Classic it was possible to spawn robots in the simulation with the launch file spawn_entity from the gazebo_ros pkg. Is there any equivalent in to that in Gazebo Ignition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gazebo Ignition, they have moved from `gazebo_ros` to `ros_gz`. Inside this `ros_gz` metapackage, you'd find the `ros_gz_sim` package, which provides the functionality that you want.

I'll point you to the source of the [package](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/ros2/ros_gz_sim), you can use this to check what types of inputs the launch file expects, and also to read more about the package. In case you are looking to use it in the ROS 2 CLI, it's

```
ros2 launch ros_gz_sim gz_sim.launch.py gz_args:="shapes.sdf"
```

I'd also point you to [this](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/migrating_gazebo_classic_ros2_packages) Migration Guide, where you have a a very nicely written document on how to migrate your project from Gazebo Classic to Gazebo Ignition. The section of interest for you would be the [spawn model](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/migrating_gazebo_classic_ros2_packages#spawn-model) section.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will take a look and test it home, the spawn functionality is definitely something that I really wanted to use